# How can I customize Catalyst::View::TTSite?

Tags: perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

I use Catalyst::View::TT and Catalyst::View::TTSite for templating, and I find the pre-created templates really useful, but would like to modify them to suit my needs.

This is because I always end up changing the header, css and layout in the same way every time I start an application (I include jquery, and bootstrap links, and use a different color schema).

How would I go about subclassing the module, and what parts should I change? I suppose the helper, but can anyone offer advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just experimenting so there is probably a better/more robust/more elegant solution.

> catalyst.pl MyApp
>
> cd MyApp
>
> mkdir -p lib/Catalyst/Helper/View
>
> wget --output-document lib/Catalyst/Helper/View/TTMySite.pm
>   http://api.metacpan.org/source/JJNAPIORK/Catalyst-View-TT-0.41/lib/Catalyst/Helper/View/TTSite.pm
>
> vim lib/Catalyst/Helper/View/TTMySite.pm
>   1. Change package name from TTSite to TTMySite
>   2. change the template source according to your requirements
>
> ./script/myapp_create.pl view HTML TTMySite

Comment: Thanks, this looks elegant enough to me. So do I understand it right that the whole thing is about changing the templates inside Catalyst/Helper/View/TTSite.pm? And I could be done by maintaining my own helper - nothing else?